# How to get more than 50K records in a trigger handler from SOQL

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, query, class

I have a requirement where I'm getting more than 50k records for a single parent id, and I need those whole records to process them.

I now batch is the best option to use but that would be time taking process. I just wanted any logic by which I can get more than 50k records and use that.

It is an urgent requirement, please share valuable answers.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a bit of time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/292121/edit) your question to add more detail.

Comment: Are you familiar with data skew in Salesforce? Best practice is to avoid having more than 10.000 children to one parent. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to load more than a total of 50K records in a given synchronous session/transaction (as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm)), and certainly no way to do this in a trigger. The only way to deal with this sort of thing is to use async processing such as in a Batchable as you mentioned.

It is possible to execute [certain types of aggregate query](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_count_limits.htm) across more records, but from what you said this approach isn't appropriate for you.

NB: Being executed from a trigger implies that you are unable to use a [readonly transaction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm) to get a higher limit.

Comment: Is there any way like if get total records which going to be retrieved from Count() and by using anything OFFSET, I first get 50k records and next by skipping 50k which already I got?

Comment: @ANKITSHARMA Unfortunately no, the 50.000 records is for the entire transaction which means you don't get to query more records after that.